# "Template is null or has zero length" with jersey declarative hyperlinking

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to integrate the declarative hyperlinking by following examples I found here and there. I came across some using `... value = "/systemusers/{id}" ...` and some using `... resource = SystemUser .class ...`. In my code, if I use the first solution I have the link correctly injected in my JSon response, while with the latter I get an `"Template is null or has zero length"` error. What is the problem and which template is the error referring to?
Here is my code snippet:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class SystemUser extends Account
{
  private String                        addrRow1;
  private String                        addrRow2;
  private String                        addrRow3;
  private String                        postCode;
  private String                        city;
  private String                        country;
  private String                        responsiblePerson;           // npid der resp. person
  private String                        responsibleAgroup;
  private String                        project;
  private String                        personRole;                  // for ex. selfreg_host, technical, nethz_guest, ...

  @InjectLink( value = "/users/{npid}", style = Style.ABSOLUTE, bindings = @Binding( name = "npid", value = "${instance.npid}" ), rel = "self" )
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter( XmlAdapter.class )
  @XmlElement( name = "link" )
  Link                                  self;
...
```

As said, if I specify the `value` parameter I get

```
"link": {
        "uri": "/IAMWS/services/users/10",
        "params": {
            "rel": "self"
        },
        "type": null,
        "rel": "self",
        "title": null,
        "rels": [
            "self"
        ],
        "uriBuilder": {
            "absolute": false
        }
    }
```

while if I specify the `resource` parameter i get:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Template is null or has zero length
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:487)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:425)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:383)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:336)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:223)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: any luck with your issues? I am facing the same trouble.

Comment: In my case, the resource was an interface rather than an implementation.
"resource = <interface>" which should have been resource = <implementation>.